# Python 3 XML parser unkown entity error

Tags: python, html, xml, parsing

However I found a lot of answers here, unfortunately, they don't work for me.

I have Ubuntu x64, python 3.4.2.

I am parsing a web page with html entities like `&nbsp;` among others:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
page = 'some string I get from requests.get'
parser = ET.XMLParser()
parser.parser.UseForeignDTD(True)
tree = ET.fromstring(page, parser=parser)
```

A lot of answers contain this code in order to prevent errors like `unknown entity &nbps;`. While I compile this code it throws an error:

`AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser' object has no attribute 'parser'`

or

`AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser' object has no attribute '_parser'`

(depdends on what member of `parser` object I wrote in 4th line in the code above). The magic is when I try to go to this code from `PyCharm` IDE it shows me that this member is exists and successfully creates in class constructor:

```
# underscored names are provided for compatibility only
self.parser = self._parser = parser
self.target = self._target = target
```

My questions are:

1. Why does not this work ?
2. Is it possible not to add each entity manually to prevent parse errors?

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this same problem myself today, although I'm on Python 2.7.3.  As far as I can see, this does work the first time you try it, but at some point the parser does indeed lose its `_parser` attribute.  If you can examine the object at the point that it throws this exception, rather than at creation, then you'll see that it's not lying.

Annoyingly I wasn't able to figure out how this happens.  I attempted to monkey-patch the `XMLParser.feed()` method, which is what throws this exception:

```
def feed(self, data):
    try:
        self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
    except self._error, v:
        self._raiseerror(v)
```

to remove the `_`, since the `parser` attribute does remain, and should be the same as `_parser`.  But then I started getting errors that suggested that the parser was still carrying state from a previous `fromstring` invocation.

Instead, what eventually worked for me was to simply recreate the `XMLParser` object every time I needed it, i.e.

```
class DecodeEntities:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in name2codepoint:
            return unichr(name2codepoint[key])
        else:
            # Note that this removes unrecognised entities
            return ''

class Parse:
    def from_unicode(self, unic):
        # We also want the parser to understand HTMLX entities.
        # Note that this has to be created every time - reusing a
        # parser appears not to be possible.
        parser = ElementTree.XMLParser()
        parser.parser.UseForeignDTD(True)
        parser.entity = DecodeEntities()

        ret = ElementTree.fromstring(unic, parser=parser)
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the [python doc:](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=xmlparser:)

> Changed in version 3.3: This module will use a fast implementation whenever available. The xml.etree.cElementTree module is deprecated.

I make some tests
in python 3.2:

```
Python 3.2.6 (default, Jan 18 2016, 19:21:14) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from xml.etree import cElementTree, ElementTree
>>> parser = ElementTree.XMLParser()
>>> cParser = cElementTree.XMLParser()
>>> type(parser)
<class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser'>
>>> type(cParser)
<class 'XMLParser'>
>>> dir(parser)
['_XMLParser__doctype', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_comment', '_data', '_default', '_doctype', '_end', '_error', '_fixname', '_names', '_parser', '_pi', '_raiseerror', '_start', '_start_list', '_target', 'close', 'doctype', 'entity', 'feed', 'parser', 'target', 'version']
>>> dir(cParser)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_parse', '_setevents', 'close', 'feed']
```

in python 3.4:

```
Python 3.4.10 (default, Mar 20 2019, 00:52:37) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from xml.etree import cElementTree, ElementTree
>>> parser = ElementTree.XMLParser()
>>> cParser = cElementTree.XMLParser()
>>> dir(parser)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_parse_whole', '_setevents', 'close', 'doctype', 'feed']
>>> dir(cParser)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_parse_whole', '_setevents', 'close', 'doctype', 'feed']
>>> type(parser)
<class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser'>
>>> type(cParser)
<class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser'>
```

Oberversly, the **xml.etree.ElementTree** is identical to **xml.etree.cElementTree** after python 3.3+